# Perspective disappeared in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, perspectives

I run Fedora 11 x86_64 and I use fedora eclipse.

Was compiling code in c++ in my c++ perspective, one of the many I had and than fedora crashed for no reason. No big deal, I just restart my system but when I reopen eclipse for me to continue coding. Eclipse has put me in a weird "resource" perspective.

So, I instinctively got to open my c++ perspective but it was no longer in the choice I was offered. I then check software updates to see if my c++ and java packages were still there and they were. So, c++ and java perspective were installed but I can't use them.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try Window->Reset Perspective?

You might also want to remove or rename your .metadata folder...